# Rails+React/Next.js: how to store code blocks so formatting persists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, database, next.js

tl;dr How should I approach storing code blocks in a react + rail application? If I were to store the code block data in the rails backend, which datatype should I store it as? And if on the frontend, would mdx files be the best solution?

I’m building a programming quiz application where a question has many answers and each answer (only one is correct) has an explanation. The question consists of the question itself and a code block, similar to what’s circled in orange in this [wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRUu6.png).

As I want to practice building Rails+React (Next.js) applications, I thought that the questions would be stored on the backend. However, is that a good idea? If so, I’m wondering about what would be a possible way to store the code snippets given the Rails datatypes?

Alternatively, I was also considering storing all the questions on the frontend. If I choose to do so, would mdx files be the best solution here?

So, to sum up, which of the following solutions would be best here:

- Storing code block as markdown files in the frontend
- Storing code block data in the backend
- Different solution altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought that the questions would be stored on the backend. However, is that a good idea?

This depends on if you want the questions and answers to be user editable. In that case you need to actually store it somewhere. That somewhere would typically be a database which your Rails app communicates with.

If you're using markdown you can use the `:text` type in ActiveRecord. The database adapter will map this to a suitible type for that database for storing long strings - the exact details vary per adapter.

> Alternatively, I was also considering storing all the questions on the
> frontend. If I choose to do so, would mdx files be the best solution
> here?

If by "storing the questions on the frontend" you mean putting them into your react project and serving them through that server (or cloud storage) then that is definately an option if you're building a very simple application where the questions and answers are a developer concern.

### TLDR;

You really need to write use cases and goals for your application. If its a learning application do you really want to learn more about the server side and writing database applications or do you want to focus on writing client side code? The answer to those questions will determine your choices.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough response! This helped me frame my question and problem better.